# How do I modify the "has_js" cookie?

Tags: 7, security, cookies

I have a web application deployed through Drupal 7.43. I need to modify the *has_js* cookie that is set by Drupal to make it both Http-only and Secure for a site security review.

What are pros and cons of making the *has_js* cookie Http-only and Secure?

Answer (score 2):

The *has_js* cookie is set, to indicate JavaScript is enabled, in drupal.js with the following code.

```
// 'js enabled' cookie.
document.cookie = 'has_js=1; path=/';
```

The *HttpOnly* flag makes the cookie not available from JavaScript.
For that reason, it's not possible to set the *HttpOnly* flag when creating a cookie from JavaScript. It may cause issues if there is code that checks for that cookie to determine if JavaScript or cookie support is enabled.

The *Secure* flag is used to make the cookie only available over HTTPS, which may cause issues with checking for JavaScript support on non HTTPS pages. Nevertheless, if your site is fully HTTPS, that should be fine.

With that being said, you could look into setting the *HttpOnly* flag on the *has_js* cookie server side, by checking for that cookie and updating it to use the *HttpOnly* flag via [`setcookie()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).